# When printing on mutiple pages in word, adobe reader etc.. how to print page 3 on the right side on the page

Tags: pdf, printing, document, cpu-word

When printing multiple pages (2 pages) in single sheet (in horizontal view), the 3rd page always gets printed on the left side of the page, can I change this setting somehow and print this page on the right instead? If yes then how can I do that?

Just to be clear, I'm asking whether we can change the order where each page to be printed.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the printing settings, you could try inserting a page break/blank page in between page 2 and 3.This will bump the existing page 3 to the right side, while keeping the left side empty.

Though this assumes you have no other pages beyond page 3. Because this shifts the further pages by 1 page